# Shortcut error in different PDF readers

Tags: hyperref, pdf, links, shortcut

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\href{https://www.gimp.org/}{GNU Image Manipulation Program}
\end{document}
```

The shortcut works correctly at Evince 3.22.0.

[image]

But shortcut works not correctly at Adobe Reader 9.5.5. Only cursor appears when clicked.

[image]

The following image appears when you click on the shortcut.

[image]

Can you help me fix the problem?

Comment: I assume you are on Linux, is that right? What exactly happens else? Is it only that the link turns into black-green?

Comment: @TeXnician, yes I'm on Ubuntu 16.10. And when clicked,  it is only that the link turns into black-green.

Comment: I can't help with this problem, but as far as I know, Adobe stopped supporting Adobe Reader on Linux two or three years ago (or more). Maybe trying to adapt to this old (and possibly buggy) version is not worth the bother?

Comment: This works for me on Linux with the latest available Reader version: 9.4 -- the link turns green with black background, but the website is opened in the preconfigured browser, which is Firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Friends who wrote messages were very helpful.

Solution, [Latest reply on May 17, 2013 7:13 AM by poisson02](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/392447) from Adobe's Forum.

`Edit > Preferences > Trust Manager > Change Settings > Allow all web sites`

At least it is working for me.